# Can chewing gum hurt a saltwater aquarium?

Tags: fish, aquarium, saltwater

My daughter and son were playing and somehow accidentally threw a piece of gum in my boyfriend's aquarium. Before I could get it out, it had already fallen behind the rocks. I'm afraid to tell him,  but I'm also afraid to not, too!  Please help.

Comment: Did you get it out? I'm sure if it just fell in it wouldn't effect anything. If it's left it, it might adjust the pH a bit (doubt it). I'd probably still take it out, I don't think leaving it will do any good.

Comment: Are the fish big enough to eat the gum?

Comment: @JamesJenkins Didn't think of that. Even if a fish can't eat it at once, they may nibble off a piece, then from there, it could get lodged somewhere internally.

Comment: If it's a reef tank, I might be worried, as it's hard to guess if anything in the gum might be toxic to coral which are typically much more sensitive than fish.

Comment: It is a reef tank.  The problem is that I can't reach it to get it. The fish aren't big enough to eat it,  but he does have a red & white striped shrimp with real long whiskers (I don't know the name). I'm afraid he or his emerald crab might get it. The gum is just lying on the sand behind rocks,  so it isn't on any corals.

Answer (score 1):

Fish can eat gum (it can be used as a bait, actually), but like us it generally just passes through their system. The real worry here is if it gets into the aquarium filter. Depending on the filter type, it could cause a jam.

Comment: This answer could use some references, Using gum as bait does not speak well to the longevity of the partaker.

Comment: Ugh... I guess I should just tell him then.

Comment: Can't even find a scientific article on the toxicity of ingredients common to gum on fish.  Can find many articles of people feeding gum to fish accidentally or as bait.